# Decision Tree binary variable node interpretation

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, decision-tree

I've built a decision tree in python using sklearn library and I've got a question how to interpret split in a node for binary variable. See a screenshot
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogOhC.png)

So I have a variable *if_successful* which is binary, where 1 indicates successful transaction and 0 not-successful. The header of that leaf says *if_successful <= 0,002*. How do I interpret this?
I thought that to the left we have **True** and **False** to the right, so *if_successful = 1* on left arrow and *if_successful = 0* on the right. However here if *if_successful <= 0,002* is True then it is basically *if_successful = 0* ? Then interpretation is the opposite and I'm quite confused about that.
How do I interpret split that header for binary variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your decision tree is treating the binary variable as a numeric variable, hence the representation `if_successful <= 0.002`. Cast the variable to binary or boolean and train the model and it will work fine and give you a `0` or `1` split.

Comment: I've converted those variables to boolean and still getting the same results -  the same headers like _if_successful <= 0.002_ even though variable is having only values of _True_ and _False_. Any other ideas?
I'm having continuous numeric variables and categorical. Do all variables has to be the same type?